# Navigation Bar with background element animation

Tags: jquery, css

I am development one menu css/javscript navigation bar, look like this.

http://www.yizztech.com/navbar/
(Example and code in this location)

Now I want one background image animation (jQuery) under elements words on hover mouse event.

Can you tell me how I can make it?

I just try with absolute elements under  elements and other ways, but allways I have problems with  sublist layout.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to explain, using some examples and try to explain your problems more clear.

Comment: With code. Your question becomes useless (as it currently stands) once that link goes dead.

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question regarding to what I found on the given site.

Change this code:

```
$('nav.yizzbar li.tablet').click(function(){
    if(!mouse){
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    }
});
```

Into:

```
$('nav.yizzbar li.tablet').click(function(){
    if(!mouse){
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Now you will see you have an animation. You can actually choose the duration and other things. It is explained here: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

For a more custom implementation, specify what kind of animation you want, and I can help you further.

Comment: For example, I want to appear one image under words list element (100% of li, background image with repeat-x) with jquery.fadeIn() animation on mouseover() event. Then I just try with one absolute and display:none div in <li> element, but is more difficult mantain sublist layout working fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get what you want to do. Maybe you should provide a specific code example of things that don't work.

Comment: Hi Friend, here I see you one example. Allways I have problems with sublist layout, specially with div.bkhocer to combine absolute, relatives, etc.. css properties to do the correct functionality. http://www.yizztech.com/navbar/

Comment: Fix it! I fix absolute behaviour with javascript to do div.bkhover the li parent width... $(this).find('.bkhover').css('width', $(this).width()).fadeIn(300);